# gimp no longer starts: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

Tags: gtk, gimp

What happened to my gimp?

```
$ dpkg --list | grep gimp
ii  gimp                                       2.10.24-2                                  amd64        GNU Image Manipulation Program
ii  gimp-data                                  2.10.24-2                                  all          Data files for GIMP
ii  gimp-dds                                   3.0.1-1build1                              amd64        DDS (DirectDraw Surface) plugin for GIMP
ii  libgimp2.0:amd64                           2.10.24-2                                  amd64        Libraries for the GNU Image Manipulation Program
$ gimp
Gtk-Message: 12:21:55.275: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

This is on an up-to-date **Ubuntu 21.10**

And the Canberra module seems to be installed just fine:

```
 dpkg --list | grep canberra
ii  gnome-session-canberra                     0.30-7ubuntu2                              amd64        GNOME session log in and log out sound events
ii  libcanberra-gtk3-0:amd64                   0.30-7ubuntu2                              amd64        GTK+ 3.0 helper for playing widget event sounds with libcanberra
ii  libcanberra-gtk3-module:amd64              0.30-7ubuntu2                              amd64        translates GTK3 widgets signals to event sounds
ii  libcanberra-pulse:amd64                    0.30-7ubuntu2                              amd64        PulseAudio backend for libcanberra
ii  libcanberra0:amd64                         0.30-7ubuntu2                              amd64        simple abstract interface for playing event sounds
```

### UPDATE

```
$ snap list | grep -i gimp
$ flatpak list | grep -i gimp
GNU Image Manipulation Program  org.gimp.GIMP   2.99.2  beta    gimp-origin user
```

Comment: Please also add output of `snap list | grep -i gimp` and `flatpak list | grep -i gimp` .

Comment: Please run `sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module` and the restart GIMP.